# Hiding a table on clicking the text inside h1 element

Tags: jquery

I want to show a table on page load but want to show/hide in an expand/collapse manner.

I am unable to do so using the following code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {     
        $("table").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        $("h1").click(function () {
            $(this).next("table").slideToggle(500);
        });
    });
});
```

Please suggest how this can be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: don't use only $('table').hide() . one day you'll add anorher table on that page and ......  You' ll came here again ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to show the page on load why are you hiding it `$("table").hide();`

you can use

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body

        $("h1").click(function () {

            $("table").slideToggle(500);

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
  $("table").hide();
});
```

You don't need to put the jQuery ready inside of the window.load, removing that wrapper should fix it.